# Cookie error with wordpress network + custom domain + ssl

Tags: wordpress, cookies, ssl

I have a network installation of wordpress. One of the blogs is configured with a custom domain and SSL. When I try to log into the admin for that site over SSL, I get the following error in Chrome:

```
ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.
```

I can log into other, non-SSL, blogs on the same network without a problem. Any idea what's going on or how to fix?